# Not finding QT4 QWidget after update

Tags: qt

Updated from buntu 11.0 to 12.04.  I use to have QT4 ver 4.7.4, now I have 4.8.1.
My project is failing to build because it can't find `#include <QWidget>`.  A search of the disk tells me there is no QWidget file.  (It was there B/4 the update.)
Other online comments say QWidget has been deprecated.  Others say it is still there, and supported.  Some say it is supported as an add-on.  I have libqt4-dev installed.  I see nothing that mentions an QWidget add-on.
So right about now I don't know what is what.  Can someone shed some light on this?

```
gcc -c viewer.cxx
In file included from viewer.cxx:2:0:  
viewer.h:5:45: fatal error: QWidget: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I get the same type of failure when I use `<QtGui/GWidget>`.  I have found the file @ `/user/include/qt4/QtGui/`  (Why I didn't find it before, I'm not sure.)  It appears I have an issue with the projects cmake.
Let me work on this for a bit.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The [`libqt4-dev` package really contains this file in 12.04!](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=QWidget.h) I believe something else is causing the issue. Can you post the exact error message you get when you compile? Also provide the output of `apt-cache policy libqt4-dev` as well as `find /usr -iname "QWidget.h" -type f` (will take a while to complete). And what happens if you use `#include <QtGui/QWidget>` instead? Do this by *editing* your question. Thanks.

Comment: *"Other online comments say QWidget has been deprecated."* They're telling lies. Maybe this is changed in 5.x of Qt, but it's definitely supported in the complete 4.x release. See also [QtWidget class reference (4.8)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html). I think your compiler just does not know where to find these Qt header files. Could you include a minimal code example (here or on paste.ubuntu.com for example)? I'll try to reproduce it here. Oh and CMake Lists file tutorial for Qt4 is [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/CMakeListsFileForQt4).

Comment: I have it compiling now.  It fails to link properly.  **undefined reference to QVTKWidget2::QVTKWidget(QWidget*, QGLWidget const*, QFlags<QT::WindowType>)**  How do I find out which lib **QVTKWidget2** is in?  i.e. Which lib is it not finding?

Comment: Good, but **please post the solution to the QWidget issue *as an answer*** to your own question. This latest comment is not Qt anymore I believe. You're trying to compile [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) stuff there... **Please ask a new question!** P.S. It may take some time before you can answer your own question while you're still on a lower reputation count.